# Sqlite finalise and Db locking issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios4

I am using the below function in my app,and i have started using the sq-lite recently and i would like to get your opinion that i am going with that correctly or not.

Since i am facing db locked issue in my app when searched i found that i need to use sqlite3 finalise statement.

what i am not sure is do i need to place one finalise statement for each sqlite3 prepare statement

Please let me know

```
- ( BOOL ) addNewCate:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)title:(NSString*)tierOneID:(NSString*)tierTwoID{

    BOOL returnVal = NO;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        const char *sql = "insert into storyboard_phrases(phrase) Values(?)";

        sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if(sqlite3_step(addStmt) != SQLITE_DONE ) {

            NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

        } else {

            NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %d", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));

            int ph_id = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

            int sub_category_id = [tierTwoID intValue];

            int main_category_id = [tierOneID intValue];

            addStmt = nil;

            sql = "insert into phrase_reference(phrase_id, sub_category_id,main_category_id) Values(?,?,?)";

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

                sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, ph_id);

                sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, sub_category_id);

                sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 3, main_category_id);

            }

            if(sqlite3_step(addStmt) != SQLITE_DONE ) {

                NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

            } else {

                NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %d", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
                returnVal = YES;


            }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hii you get the locked issues in log right, that means your database is **open** and you doing some changes in that database so **close** database and try again to run application and  insert in table...

hope this will help you..